# Tab items in a tab control appears blurred

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am working on a `WPF` application where I have a `TabControl` with three Tabs and I have increased the size of tabs according to the content but the tabs appear to be blurred as in the following picture

[image]

XAML code is as follows

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,0,-3,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="665" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <TabControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0.215"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TabControl.RenderTransform>
```

**Is there a good way I can fix it?**

Comment: There are many ways to resize something. Post the XAML code.

Comment: Why are you rotating your tabs by 0.215 degrees?  That would seem to have very little visual effect except for making your content blurry.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of text rendering in WPF.These articles may help you.

[One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2009/10/21/new-wpf-features-textformattingmode-for-clear-text.aspx)

[Two](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/control-concepts/text-rendering/)

[Three](https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/much-improved-net-4-0-wpf-text-rendering/)